# Eclipse outline plugin ContentOutlinePage not found

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am making an eclipse plugin and I want to make the Outline view. I want to extend ContentOutlinePage. But my eclipse cannot resolve it.

Should I add something to plugin.xml to make it find the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add org.eclipse.ui.views to the Dependencies tab.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to define dependencies properly for your plug-in. In your case you would probably need at least: org.eclipse.ui.editors, org.eclipse.ui.ide. Please add them on to the manifest (on the Dependencies tab of plug-in/manifest editor).